# angular wait for parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, parent-child, angularjs-routing, angularjs-module

I have an angular application and several modules.
As you can see below, i am calling a directive that in mod2, at the mod1template.html.
myvar gets value in mod1Ctrl
But angular initialize child first and myvar appears empty in mod2's controller.
When i googled it, there are some solutions but anything for my case.
pre post links works for when both parent and child are directives but my mod1 haven't any directive.
I don't want to pass parameter as attribute

Is there any more solutions for my case ?

```
mod1template.html:
<div>
<mod2-dir></mod2-dir>
</div>
```

```
angular.module("angApp.mod1", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/:myvar1/:myvar2\\_:id", {
            templateUrl: "Angular/mod1template.html",
            controller: "mod1Ctrl"
        });

    }])
    .controller("mod1Ctrl", ["$routeParams", "$scope", "mod1DataService", function ($routeParams, $scope, mod1DataService) {
        $scope.myvar = mod1DataService.myvar;
        }
```

```
angular.module("angApp.mod2", ["ngRoute"])
    .directive("mod2Dir", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "Angular/mod2template.html",
            controller: "mod2Ctrl"
        };
    })
    .controller("mod2Ctrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        alert($scope.myvar.Id);
        }
```

Comment: you could use $broadcast or $emit depending ob how controller placed.

Comment: thank you very much, $broadcast worked for me. if you post it as answer i can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Could use $broadcast In your case. When $scope.myvar value change,watch will fire broadcast event and it will be listen by its child scope.

```
angular.module("angApp.mod1", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/:myvar1/:myvar2\\_:id", {
            templateUrl: "Angular/mod1template.html",
            controller: "mod1Ctrl"
        });

    }])
    .controller("mod1Ctrl", ["$routeParams", "$scope", "mod1DataService", function ($routeParams, $scope, mod1DataService) {
        $scope.myvar = mod1DataService.myvar;
        //asuming that service call is ajax that's why placing watch on on myvar
        $scope.$watch('myvar', function(newVal, oldVal){
          if(newVal != oldVal)
             $scope.$broadcast('parentControllerLoaded',newVal); //no need to use broadcast event using $rootScope
        },true);
    }



angular.module("angApp.mod2", ["ngRoute"])
    .directive("mod2Dir", function () {
    return {
       restrict: "E",
       templateUrl: "Angular/mod2template.html",
       controller: "mod2Ctrl"
   };
})
.controller("mod2Ctrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('parentControllerLoaded',function(event, data){
        alert(data.id);
        //you can directly access parent scope from here.
        //alert($scope.$parent.myvar.Id)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using $timeout in mod2Ctrl:

instead of

```
alert($scope.myvar.Id);
```

use this

```
$timeout(function(){
    alert($scope.myvar.Id);
},1);
```

Comment: thank you but i don't think $timeout is the best way. when i tried with timeout delay with 1, it didn't work than i try with 500 it worked. the delay changes depend on many things.